# Golang using golang dep with dep

Tags: go

I use the go dep tool version v0.4.1, now when I run dep init it create 2 files as expected , when I open the `gopkg.lock` I found for example the following

```
[[projects]]
  name = "github.com/inconshreveable/mousetrap"
  packages = ["."]
  revision = "76626ae9c91c4f2a10f34cad8ce832c93bb75"
  version = "v1.0"
```

I dont use this im my source code, search it deeply also on vendor, so why it's there, what am I missing here ? 
if it transitive dep I need to find usage of it in vendor library, isnt it ?

Comment: Have you tried to run something like `dep status -dot` ? It should print the dependencies tree. More info [here](https://golang.github.io/dep/docs/daily-dep.html#visualizing-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

You can visualize dependencies using following the command.

### Linux

```
$ sudo apt-get install graphviz
$ dep status -dot | dot -T png | display
```

### macOS

```
$ brew install graphviz
$ dep status -dot | dot -T png | open -f -a /Applications/Preview.app
```

### Windows

```
> choco install graphviz.portable
> dep status -dot | dot -T png -o status.png; start status.png
```

For the detailed information how to use dep command to show your dependencies, you can find it [here](https://golang.github.io/dep/docs/daily-dep.html)